# String Operations in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to check the distribution of a box I am deploying to with ansible. I have a database that has something like "ubuntu lucid" in a column for distro and I want to check both the distribution `ansible_distribution` and `ansible_distribution_release`. Is there a way to either concatenate those two strings to match them against my database value or to split the database value in the ansible role?

I am referencing the documentation [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate vars with Jinja variable expansion:

```
"{{ ansible_distribution }}{{ ansible_distribution_release }}"
```

or split your database var with:

```
- name: Database var converted to a list
  debug: var="{{ item }}" 
  with_items: "database_var.split(' ')"
```